# How to make an information box with selection on top?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the same thing as shown in the attached picture:

> [image: Information box with selection on top]

I've been looking for an answer online for ages, but I can't seem to find the solution. Do I just make a `<div>` and attach another `<div>` on top of it?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very simple example for you

```js
$("#tab1").click(function() {
  $("#section2").hide();
  $("#section1").show();
});

$("#tab2").click(function() {
  $("#section1").hide();
  $("#section2").show();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#section2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="tab1">Tab 1</li>
      <li id="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="section1">
    Content 1
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    Content 2
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: and when you will have 5 or more tabs? I don't think it's a suitable solution

Comment: .. so don't provide any code then ;) flag the question and downvote it

Comment: Yeah I though about this and add a comment about tab heading